# How to create a file table in MS SQL 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, blob

I need to create a table that contains a cell with a file or the path of file, and it will be used for the user download the PDFs file for example.

I'm using MS SQL 2008, VB/ASP.NET.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you have a few options, depending on the size of your files.  You can either store the data inside the database itself via the normal table structure (as BLOB data):

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FileStorage
(
    FileName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FileType VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    FileCOntents VARBINARY(MAX) NOT NULL
)
```

Another option is to just store the path as you said:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FileStorage
(
    FileName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FileType VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)
```

Lastly, using the FileStram feature in SQL Server 2008+:

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.FileStorage
(
    FileName VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    FileType VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL,
    FileCOntents VARBINARY(MAX) FILESTREAM NOT NULL
)
```

There is more set-up involved, but it is supported using .NET filestreams, so it is really nice from a development perspective.  Here's a link describing more:
https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/an-introduction-to-sql-server-filestream/

Also, more on when to use filestreams:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh461480.aspx

Answer (score 0):

You can store your PDF in the SQL server database as a BLOB, but better way is to store just a file path as a string.

```
CREATE TABLE MyFIleInfo(
ID int NOT NULL,
FilePath nvarchar(MAX) NOT NULL
)
```

For last several years, I'm working with Hyland Software OnBase product (digital imaging solution) this is exactly how they are storing scans and other uploaded documents. Product is very fast and works great

Comment: Thank you, I think this way is really better, but I needed to know about the sintax. Thanks anyway!